# Bulk error on date field but insert into works SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm trying to bulk insert into a table but i keep getting this error

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (HEURE).

Here's the create script for my table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GST_TempDelete]
(
    [HEURE] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [Typebase] [FLOAT] NULL,
    [DATE] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [CHP] [NVARCHAR](4000) NULL,
    [tab] [NVARCHAR](4000) NULL,
    [ref1] [NVARCHAR](400) NULL,
    [ref2] [NVARCHAR](400) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This is the content of the file I'm trying to use for the bulk insert

```
14:50:07|1|21/03/2019|SOMETEXT|PARAMbase|00000|54141|
14:50:07|1|21/03/2019|TEST|TEST|00000|54141|
```

Here's the bulk insert query

```
SET LANGUAGE FRENCH 

BULK INSERT GST_TempDelete   
FROM 'D:\TEST_DATA\TEMP\bulkInsert.txt' 
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR ='|',ROWTERMINATOR = '|')
```

When I try inserting data with `INSERT INTO` using the values from the bulk file, it works, but the `bulk insert` itself keeps failing.

Here's the `INSERT INTO` query:

```
INSERT INTO GST_TempDelete 
VALUES ('14:50:07', '1', '21/03/2019', 'TEST', 'TEST', '00000', '54141')
```

Please, help me solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Column HEURE is a datetime column so you need to add date as well in the '14:50:07' value.

Comment: I tried it but no go, but the insert into without date works

Comment: try to find the input data for the error and try that data insert manually, then you can see the real error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **14:50:07**|1|21/03/2019|SOMETEXT|PARAMbase|00000|54141|

The first column in a CSV file is obviously in a time format. While it has DATETIME type in the DDL of the table. So, seems it to be changed from `DATETIME`  to `TIME`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GST_TempDelete](
    [HEURE] [time] NULL,
    [Typebase] [float] NULL,
    [DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [CHP] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [tab] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [ref1] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [ref2] [nvarchar](400) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET LANGUAGE FRENCH 
BULK INSERT GST_TempDelete   FROM 'D:\TEST_DATA\TEMP\bulkInsert.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR ='|',ROWTERMINATOR = '|')
```

> When i try inserting data with Insert into using the values from the
>   bulk file, it works but the bulk insert itself keeps failing

This could be because:

> BULK INSERT enforces strict data validation and data checks of data
>   read from a file that could cause existing scripts to fail when they
>   are executed on invalid data.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue: its for the date column. '21/03/2019' is the right value.

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
insert into GST_TempDelete values('14:50:07','1.0','21/03/2019','TEST','TEST','00000','54141')
```